# What does Wolfram's $n_{\#1}(1)$ mean?

Tags: notation

> What does Wolfram's $n_{\#1}(1)$ mean in the answer [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C-4%2B8cos%5E2%28%CE%B1%29%2B8cos%5E2%28%CE%B2%29%2B4cos%5E2%28%CE%B2-%CE%B1%29%7C%3D1)? The input is, in code,  `|-4+8cos^2(α)+8cos^2(β)+4cos^2(β-α)|=1`.

[image]

I haven't got a clue.

Comment: Looks like they're just parameters (in this case restricted to $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Okay, @DanielFischer, but I doubt it; I didn't use $n$. I've included the input in the question now.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, @DanielFischer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order the close the question, here is a community wiki of @DanielFischer's comment.

> Looks like they're just parameters (in this case restricted to $\Bbb Z$).